# Kafka compaction for de-duplication

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand how Kafka compaction works and have the following question: Does kafka guarantees uniqueness of keys for messages stored in topic with enabled compaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Kafka doesn't guarantees uniqueness for key stored with enabled topic retention.

In Kafka you have two types of `cleanup.policy`:

- `delete` - It means that after configured time messages won't be available. There are several properties, that can be used for that: `log.retention.hours`, `log.retention.minutes`, `log.retention.ms`. By default `log.retention.hours` is set `168`. It means, that messages *older* than 7 days will be *deleted*
- `compact` - For each key at least one message will be available. In some situation it can be one, but in the most cases it will be more. Compaction processed is run in background periodically. It copies log parts with removing duplicates and only leaving last value.

If you want to read only one value for each key, you have to use `KTable<K,V>` abstraction from **Kafka Streams**.

Related question regarding latest value for key and compaction:
[Kafka only subscribe to latest message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256783/kafka-only-subscribe-to-latest-message/54257047#54257047)

Comment: Adding to this answer, you can configure one more policy that is combined of both "compact, delete" which deletes the log segments that are older than the given `log.retention.hours` and compacts the remaining log segments. Note, log compaction happens only in the older / passive segments.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at 4 [guarantees of kakfa compaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_compactionguarantees), number 4 states:

> Any consumer progressing from the start of the log will see **at least
>   the final state** of all records in the order they were written.
>   Additionally, all delete markers for deleted records will be seen,
>   provided the consumer reaches the head of the log in a time period
>   less than the topic's delete.retention.ms setting (the default is 24
>   hours). In other words: since the removal of delete markers happens
>   concurrently with reads, it is possible for a consumer to miss delete
>   markers if it lags by more than delete.retention.ms.

So, you will have more than one value for the key if the head of the topic is not being retained by the `delete.retention.ms` policy.

As I understand it, if you set a 24h retention policy (`delete.retention.ms=86400000`), you'll have a unique value for a single key, for all messages that were from 24h ago. That's your **at least**, but not only, as many other messages for the same key may have arrived during the last 24 hours.

So, it is guaranteed that you'll catch at least one, but not just the last, because retention didn't act on recent messages.

edit. As cricket's comment states, even if you set a delete retention property of 1 day, the `log.roll.ms` is what defines when a log segment is closed, based on message's timestamp. As this last segment is never retained for compaction, it becomes the second factor that doesn't allow you having **just the last value** for your known key. If your topic starts at `T0`, then messages after `T0+log.roll.ms` will be on the open log segment, thus, not compacted.

Comment: To clarify the last few sections, open log segments are not compacted. It's not only the delete retention that matters, but the log segment size

Comment: completely true @cricket_007. Thanks for clarifying that concept and completing my answer.