# Is Kafka Log compaction also a de-duplication mechanism

Tags: apache-kafka

Is Kafka Log compaction also a de-duplication mechanism

I have gone through this post [Kafka compaction for de-duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298063/kafka-compaction-for-de-duplication)

which states Kafka Log compaction is not a deduplication mechanism.But i still few doubts.

q3)I am not able to understand understand how log compaction is not preventing duplicate reads.

```
 Suppose Producer sends 2 records
 Key : Employee1 { Salary :1000 } 
Key : Employee1 { Salary :2000 } 

Consumer hasn't read the data yet.
Log Compaction happens
we have one only record
Key : Employee1 { Salary :2000 } 
Consumer reads data now
```

So consumer is only reading  `Key : Employee1 { Salary :2000 }` .hence duplicate read is prevented.Where i am going wrong?
And what is meant by log compaction happens only when "segment is committed "?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the situation that you've described i.e. Consumer hasn't read the data yet and the compaction happens - Yes, in this case the duplicate reads may be prevented.

But...

- If the compaction has not happened, you will still see duplicates.
- The config `delete.retention.ms (default value of 24 hours)` allows the deleted records to be seen by consumers, which could lead to the duplicates reaching the consumers. Those messages will have a deletion mark.
- **Your 2nd question** - The compaction happens only on committed segments and not active segments. The messages in any Kafka partition are arranged in segments on the disk. Once the size of the segment has reached 1 GB or the segment is 7 days old - whichever is smaller - the segment gets closed or committed. These settings of 1 GB o 7 days are obviously configurable. Then, a new segment is opened and the new messages get written to this new segment. Now, if duplicates are being written to this active segment and if the consumer is continuously reading - which is often the case - the duplicates will be read.

So, if you think about it, you will ***NOT*** be able to rely on just the compaction feature alone to achieve de-duplication. Moreover, it is ***NOT*** something that can be triggered using an API (at least not yet) so you won't be able to control it in your consumer application either.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.So  if write 2 messages with same key and it is in active segment...data compaction wont take place and if consumer reads he will see both the messages right?

Comment: @amitjain - So if you think your question has been answered, then could you please acknowledge/accept the answer? :)

Comment: `Log compaction ensures that Kafka will always retain at least the last known value for each message key within the log of data for a single topic partition.` So even after log compaction has occurred it does not gurantee that we will get only the latest value for the key.,We might see duplicates too despite the log compaction.Am i right ?

Comment: I think you've raised a very subtle point. The word "at least" - I think it probably refers to the whole log of data within that partition rather than just the compacted part. So, if there is a duplicate key in the active segment then you would definitely have duplicates. But, could there be circumstances where within the compacted part we've got duplicates? Hmm.... May be but my take is that we will not but it's worth a new question. People in rest of Kafka community might give us some more insight.